# Creating a Css Button with fixed size but centered elements

Tags: html, css, button

I'm trying to create a Button with an Image on the Right side. But when I set the width of my innerContainer to auto it choses the maximum width.

To realize this, there was a need to create some wrappers.

```css
div.container {   
  max-width: 240px; 
  width: auto;
  border: 5px solid #cd8102;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: 36px;
  background: linear-gradient(#fcbf00, #f39600); /* Standard syntax */
  font-family: 'PT Sans',sans-serif;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
div.container:hover{
  background: linear-gradient(yellow, #f39600); /* Standard syntax */
}
div.innerContainer{
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto; 
  border: 2px solid black;
}
div.box1 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 207;
  max-width: 207px;
  /*border: 1px solid red; */
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  float: left;
  height: 36px;    
  text-align: center;
  padding-right: 6px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
div.box2 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  float: left;
  justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
  align-items: center; /* align vertical */

}
#TextInTheMiddle {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
  align-items: center; /* align vertical */ 
  height: 36px;    
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.google.de" >
  <div class="container">
    <div class="innerContainer">
      <div class="box1">
        <span id='TextInTheMiddle'>Weiter Einkaufen</span>
      </div>
      <div class="box2">
        <span>
          <img id="img" src="file:///Y|/Button/images/icons/next.png" height="20" width="20">
        </span>
      </div>
      <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

The black border should ending with the blue one on the right side and also be centered within the button. I can be viewed in the js fiddle Demo.

[Jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nixjack/zf48u7as/)

Comment: You should seriously rethink your markup. It can be done a lot of  easier (and thus cleaner), perhaps you want to look at some of the other solutions presented below.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I already thought that there is a easyer to create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```css
div.container {   
  text-align: center;
}
div.innerContainer{
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto; /* default value */
}
```

```css
div.container {   
  max-width: 240px; 
  width: auto;
  border: 5px solid #cd8102;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: 36px;
  background: linear-gradient(#fcbf00, #f39600); /* Standard syntax */
  font-family: 'PT Sans',sans-serif;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
div.container:hover{
  background: linear-gradient(yellow, #f39600); /* Standard syntax */
}
div.innerContainer{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto; 
  border: 2px solid black;
}
div.box1 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 207;
  max-width: 207px;
  /*border: 1px solid red; */
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  float: left;
  height: 36px;    
  text-align: center;
  padding-right: 6px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
div.box2 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  float: left;
  justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
  align-items: center; /* align vertical */

}
#TextInTheMiddle {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
  align-items: center; /* align vertical */ 
  height: 36px;    
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.google.de" >
  <div class="container">
    <div class="innerContainer">
      <div class="box1">
        <span id='TextInTheMiddle'>Weiter Einkaufen</span>
      </div>
      <div class="box2">
        <span>
          <img id="img" src="file:///Y|/Button/images/icons/next.png" height="20" width="20">
        </span>
      </div>
      <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that's what you were looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/zf48u7as/1/

```
div.innerContainer{
    /* add this and remove width: */
    display: inline-block;
}

div.container {   
    /* add this: */
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want the picture outside of the box? This is what I got from it:

```
div.innerContainer{

    margin: auto;
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 270px;
}
div.box2 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    text-align: center
    border: 1px solid blue;
    float: right;
    justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
    align-items: center; /* align vertical */

}
```

Changed the `width: 270px;` for the `innerContainer` and `float: right;` for the `box2`
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nixjack/zf48u7as/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting divs and spans you can customize the button like this :

```css
input#button{
  width: 75px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #838383;
  color: #fff;
  background-image: url('someImage');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-x: 50px;
  text-indent: -20px;
  }
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="button" />
```

Answer (score -1):

That looks like an aweful lot of unnecessary code. I've reduced it as much as possible to match what I thought you were trying to achieve:

To achieve this, there is not much to do:

- center the text via an according `line-height` and `text-align`
- insert the image as background image with an appropriate padding to the parent element

To further improve your code, you could use a button element (the appropriate element when you want to have a button) and some pseudo elements to position your image, but this solution works as well.

```css
div.container {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: 5px solid #cd8102;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: 36px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#fcbf00, #f39600);
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* added for centering the text*/
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 36px;
}
div.container:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(yellow, #f39600);
}
.container span {
  /* the image to the right of the text */
  padding-right: 25px;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/sports-q-c-20-20-6.jpg) right center no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.google.de">
  <div class="container">
    <span>
    Weiter Einkaufen
    </span>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: The solution looks good, but one problem appears, if I put long text in it, there is no line-break and no two-line layout. Next problem is with long text, the Image will leave the button.

Comment: @m4xx well, that's because you declared a fixed with on the container div. If you take that out and declare `display:inline-block` instead, everything works fine. Also one can declare `white-space:nowrap` to prevent text from wrapping onto several lines. I modified my answer to reflect that.